# Outputting left audio through left monitor and right audio through right monitor (windows 11)

Tags: audio, multiple-monitors

I recently got my work monitors upgraded and these have onboard sound, and it got me thinking, as dual monitor set-up are getting all the more common, wouldn't it be good to be able to use the onboard sound as a stereo separation?

Given, for visual ease, I figure most will be like me and have the monitors equally spaced left and right, ideal for outputting audio in stereo.

Have googled a bit for a result and seen recommendations for using Voicemeter - but this seems to output stereo to both monitors, which isn't quite what I'm after.

(connected over displayport if that has a bearing, using intel UHD graphics on the cpu)

Comment: Are you using one DP port on pc and daisy chaining monitors?  Would be helpful to share make and model of various hw.

Answer (score 0):

Go into the System > Sound, and in the output section adjust the left channel sound down for one monitor and the right channel down for the other monitor